# How do I "pin" Notes in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, notes.app

The [official feature list](http://www.apple.com/osx/whats-new/features.html#notes) for Mountain Lion says that individual notes opened into their own windows from the Notes app (1.0) remain "pinned" open "even if you close Notes", but this isn't true. Closing Notes closes any notes that have been opened into their own windows.

How do I get the Notes app's note "pinning" feature to work as described.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature description is a bit misleading. It appears that by "close Notes", Apple means "close the main Notes window", not "close the Notes app", which (not surprisingly) leaves other windows open.

In fact, the context menu refers to the main Notes window as *Notes*:

[image]

So what Apple's description basically means:

> Even if you close Notes, the note stays open on your desktop.

= You don't need to use the overview window at all times. You can use `Notes.app` similar to `Stickies.app`

By the way, `Stickies.app` is still available in Mountain Lion and has been upgraded to version 9.0.

Comment: Do your "pinned" notes (notes open in separate windows) stay open when you quit the Notes app?

Comment: See the updated answer. I think the wording by Apple is a bit unlucky.

Comment: I'll take that as an answer with an emphasis on the "unlucky" (or maybe even misleading) instead of "as described".

Comment: I tired editing your answer but it got rejected, so I've added a rephrasing as a CW. Feel free to use that in a rewrite and I'll accept.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Ok, I've edited the answer again.

Answer (score 1):

The feature description is a bit misleading. It appears that by "close Notes", Apple means "close the main Notes window", not "close the Notes app", which (not surprisingly) leaves other windows open.

Answer (score 0):

Double click the name of a note on the overview pane where it lists your notes. It will pop out into its own window. You can then close the main notes window, but the extra window will stay open and act like a stickie note.

Comment: Sorry, you can't quit notes, but you can close the window.

Answer (score 0):

Two workarounds (for Mac OS X) to get the 'pins' (double click the listed note) in Notes to reopen on quit and restart/shutdown. Now you can use Notes the same way you used Stickies.

Works on quit and restart/shutdown:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Navigate to the General Pane.
3. Uncheck *'Close windows when quitting an application'*

Works only on restart/shutdown:
Check the *'Reopen windows when logging back in'* box that appears in the middle of the screen on restart/shutdown.

NB! One can restore the overview window by pressing <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd> (zero).

Answer (score -1):

To contribute to this discussion, and to the confusion caused by this "feature": yes, indeed, you can close the main notes window, after "pinning" one or more separate notes, but you cannot open it anymore. When you click the notes app, only the then open pinned notes will become active. You have to close all your pinned notes first, if you want to re-open the main notes window in order to create a new note, or to open another one. 
This is very annoying indeed.

In addition, when you pin a note, close the main window, then close the pinned notes in order to re-open the main notes window, you may will find your previously pinned notes in double, or even triplicate when you select to view "All Notes". As it turns out, the previously "pinned" notes are now appearing both in their original folder (in my case in iCloud), *and* in the "recovered items" folder under "On My Mac".

Comment: You *can* re-open the main notes window. Just go to *menubar > window > notes*.